# How do I check that values are being inserted into a table when the result of the insert shows nothing?

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller

I've ran into an issue concerning a SQL Server procedure that is supposed to insert data into three tables. The code below shows that the procedure takes in parameters and then inserts said parameters into three tables: an `Address` table, a `D.O.B` table and a `Users` table.

Ignoring the salt as that has to do with something else, my issue is that when I run this procedure from an ASP.NET MVC file, nothing is inserted into the `Users` table, even though the `Address` and `D.O.B` table both have their respective values inserted into them. I've had an issue like this before which was solved because the problem was that one of the values was returning NULL when I used a HASHBYTES procedure on it, however, here there is nothing that I can think that would be doing something similar.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoreDetails]
    @FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    @Surname VARCHAR(50),
    @Password VARCHAR(100),
    @PhoneNumber VARCHAR(50),
    @Email VARCHAR(100), 
    @IsAdmin BIT,
    @Address VARCHAR(100),
    @DOB DATE
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @Salt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID()

    INSERT INTO dbo.OAddress(Address)
    VALUES (@Address)

    INSERT INTO dbo.ODOB(DOB)
    VALUES (@DOB)

    INSERT INTO dbo.OUsers (FirstName, Surname, Password, Salt, PhoneNumber, Email, IsAdmin, AddressID, DOBID)
    VALUES (@FirstName, @Surname, @Password, @Salt, @PhoneNumber, @Email, @IsAdmin, SCOPE_IDENTITY(), SCOPE_IDENTITY())
END
```

The C# side of this I believe does work as intended as not too long ago I managed to get this code to work  until I changed the stored procedure to try and change the `Password` parameter to get hashed using HASHBYTES however I decided to just revert back to when it worked normally but as you can see I'm failing.

Comment: You are probably getting a foreign key violation. You are using SCOPE_IDENTITY for for the Address and DOB ids which is highly unlikely what you want.

Comment: Did you try to call this SP from Sql Server Management Studio?

Comment: You must be getting an error from SQL server-side, Run procedure from the SQL server management studio to know the exact issue, The issue could be due to foreign key constraints.

Comment: What exactly do you expect from those **two** `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` calls in your last insert? This seems very very fishy......

Comment: @marc_s the SCOPE_IDENTITY() procedures are called as it's a convoluted way of getting the correct foreign keys assigned to the entity in the OUser table.

Comment: Yeah, but the way you're using it here **cannot** possibly work - you'd have to call `SCOPE_IDENTITY` **right after** the insert into the two tables, and store those values into SQL Server variables, and then use those variables in the `INSERT`- you cannot call `SCOPE_IDENTITY` twice to get the "last two identity values inserted" - or whatever you're expecting to get here.....

Comment: @marc_s It 'works' because it's only getting the scope_identity of the last inserted DOBID which because it's inserted in the same procedure as the AddressID so the two ID's end up having the same value. It's real weird I know hence why I'm trying to find another way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like what you likely need is a couple of `OUTPUT` clauses and some table variables:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoreDetails] @FirstName varchar(50),
                                     @Surname varchar(50),
                                     @Password varchar(100),
                                     @PhoneNumber varchar(50),
                                     @Email varchar(100),
                                     @IsAdmin bit,
                                     @Address varchar(100),
                                     @DOB date
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Salt uniqueidentifier = NEWID();
    DECLARE @AddressID table (ID int);
    DECLARE @DOBID table (ID int);

    INSERT INTO dbo.OAddress ([Address])
    OUTPUT inserted.ID
    INTO @AddressID (ID) --Guessed named for inserted
    SELECT @Address;

    INSERT INTO dbo.ODOB (DOB)
    OUTPUT inserted.ID
    INTO @DOBID (ID) --Guessed named for inserted
    SELECT @DOB;

    INSERT INTO dbo.OUsers (FirstName,
                            Surname,
                            Password,
                            Salt,
                            PhoneNumber,
                            Email,
                            IsAdmin,
                            AddressID,
                            DOBID)
    SELECT @FirstName,
           @Surname,
           @Password,
           @Salt,
           @PhoneNumber,
           @Email,
           @IsAdmin,
           A.ID,
           D.ID
    FROM @AddressID A
         CROSS JOIN @DOBID D;
END;
```

Note the comments I make on the `OUTPUT` clauses.

Comment: There is no reason to use the insert/select statement to insert a single row populated from scalar variables. Not to add the additional complication of using the output clause. And then you cross join the tables used in the output clause. WAY more complicated than needed. The proper use of SCOPE_IDENTITY would be far more appropriate to this situation and to the skill level of OP.

Comment: Which you would still need to assign to a variable after each `INSERT`, @SMor . just because you think, however, that the OP skill level won't understand the `OUTPUT` clause doesn't mean that won't and this shows how they would handle process that need to `INSERT` multiple rows. `OUTPUT`, however, is not a complicated clause.

Comment: @Larnu I'm afraid SMor is right, my skill level with SQL is very much beginner. I think I understand the OUTPUT clauses but please correct me if I'm wrong: the Address is inserted into the address table and the OUTPUT returns the ID of the inserted address. The FROM and CROSS JOIN part however is completely lost on me.

Comment: `FROM` is a very basic keyword in SQL, @Displaza ; if you're not familar with that keyword then your knowledge of SQL is lacking some *very* fundamental parts and I suggest you start by reading up on basic `SELECT` statements (which will include a `FROM`). As for `CROSS JOIN` this creates a [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the rows from the 2 tables (which in this case will only contain 1 row anyway).

Comment: @Larnu I know what ```FROM``` does just not in the context of being used with a local variable. Also why not use something like ```INNER JOIN``` instead of ```CROSS JOIN```?

Comment: `@DOBID` is a table though, @Displaza , so it's no different to a normal `FROM`. An `INNER JOIN` required an `ON` clause, but there is no inherent relation between the row in `@DOBID` and the row in `@AddressID` other than the row that *does not exist yet* in `OUsers`; therefore you can't use an `INNER JOIN`. `ON A.ID = D.ID` isn't going to be correct, as the 2 rows could easily have different ID values.

Comment: @Larnu I think I get it now. Thank you very much for clearing it up for me

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out what the database is telling you about the problem.

Put a breakpoint in your code and then grab all the values that the variables contain that you are putting into your parameters. Then switch to SQL, set up all your variables, and try running the statements from the procedure, and get the error message. Something like this:

```
declare @FirstName VARCHAR(50) = 'John'
declare @Surname VARCHAR(50) = 'Smith'
declare @Password VARCHAR(100) = 'Hek3$s*aSf8'
declare @PhoneNumber VARCHAR(50) = '333-333-3333'
declare @Email VARCHAR(100) = 'john@mailinator.com'
declare @IsAdmin BIT = 0
declare @Address VARCHAR(100) = '100 Somewhere Street, Somewheretown'
declare @DOB date = '2019-10-10'

DECLARE @Salt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER=NEWID()

INSERT INTO dbo.OAddress(Address)
VALUES(@Address)

INSERT INTO dbo.ODOB(DOB)
VALUES(@DOB)

INSERT INTO dbo.OUsers(FirstName,Surname,Password,Salt,PhoneNumber,Email,IsAdmin,AddressID,DOBID)
VALUES(@FirstName,@Surname,@Password,@Salt,@PhoneNumber,@Email,@IsAdmin,SCOPE_IDENTITY(),SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

I think we probably need to suspect the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function calls, but there's only one way to find out: run it and see.

Comment: Yeah, I executed the procedure with some fake variables and it returned with 'The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_OUsers_OAddress".'

Comment: It means that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is not getting the correct key values in the correct order. If we look at the order of operations we: 1) insert into OAddress, then 2) insert into ODOB. But then in the insert statement, we ask `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` for the AddressID but since the last insert was to ODOB, we get the DOBID instead, and boom--FK conflict. You could try switching `AddressID,DOBID` in the insert statement to `DOBID,AddressID`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the use of `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. This returns the last identity value generated by the insert statement. In your code, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is returning the value inserted for `dbo.oDOB`.

In order for this to work, you would need to capture the value for `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` into a local variable after each of the insert statements, then use those values in your final insert into `dbo.oUsers`.

The following should get you what you want:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoreDetails]
    @FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    @Surname VARCHAR(50),
    @Password VARCHAR(100),
    @PhoneNumber VARCHAR(50),
    @Email VARCHAR(100), 
    @IsAdmin BIT,
    @Address VARCHAR(100),
    @DOB DATE
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @addressKey INT,
            @dobKey INT;

    DECLARE @Salt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID();

    INSERT INTO dbo.OAddress(Address)
    VALUES (@Address);

    SET @addressKey = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    INSERT INTO dbo.ODOB(DOB)
    VALUES (@DOB);

    SET @dobKey = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    INSERT INTO dbo.OUsers (FirstName, Surname, Password, Salt, PhoneNumber, Email, IsAdmin, AddressID, DOBID)
    VALUES (@FirstName, @Surname, @Password, @Salt, @PhoneNumber, @Email, @IsAdmin, @addressKey, @dobKey)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should run stored procedure with the params to know what are error messages exactly.

Secondly, You should [handle error message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) inner stored procedure and check after each time you inserted. 
For example:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.OAddress(Address)
VALUES(@Address)

IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
      PRINT N'A check constraint violation occurred.';
      Return;
END
GO
```

However, You should also use out put param then *RETURN @@ERROR* to check in c# whether it's inserted successfully or not